# Game project not launching after building in XNA

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna

I'm brand new to XNA games development and am currently practising to make games.

I started by creating a simple platformer, and slowly built up the logic of the game and game features. My most recent addition seems to have broken the project. It started after adding a health bar function, where I add 11 textures (health bar empty, health bar 1/10, health bar 2/10 etc...).

When the player encounters a harmful object such as a spike in the game, the texture displayed for the health bar change (so if health bar was on 9, the texture would change to healthBar8).

The issue started off as an actual error preventing the project to build which was caused by having two of the same project open in two different Visual Studio windows. (This was so stupid of me and I googled how to fix the given error before finding out that I had two windows open). The suggested fix was to enter these two lines in the pre-build command line box:

> > if exist "$(TargetPath).locked" del "$(TargetPath).locked"
> >     if exist "$(TargetPath)" if not exist "$(TargetPath).locked" move "$(TargetPath)" "$(TargetPath).locked"

This seemed to have fixed the error but now my project only builds and doesn't launch, so I closed the extra window I discovered I had open and removed the two lines from the pre-build command line box, but now the project just builds and doesn't launch.

I tried creating a new project, and checked to see if it built (it did, so Visual Studio itself is not the problem) then copied and pasted the broken project's code into this new project, which still didn't launch.

I have no idea what is causing this and it's extremely annoying. I'm really sorry if my question is stated poorly as this is my first Stack overflow question (because I have never felt the need to actually post question on the internet), but I can't find a solution after extensive googling.

```
public class MainGame : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    SpriteFont coinCount;

    List<PlatformSprite> platformsList;
    List<Consumable> pickUpList;
    List<StaticEnemy> staticEnemyList;

    //public Texture2D currentHealthTexture;
    //Texture2D healthEmpty;
    //Texture2D health1;
    //Texture2D health2;
    //Texture2D health3;
    //Texture2D health4;
    //Texture2D health5;
    //Texture2D health6;
    //Texture2D health7;
    //Texture2D health8;
    //Texture2D health9;
    //Texture2D healthFull;

    //List<Texture2D> healthBarsList;

    Texture2D coinAnim;
    Texture2D coinAnimBig;
    Texture2D floatingPlatform;
    Texture2D groundPlatform;
    Texture2D redPlayer;
    Texture2D spikeEnemy;

    Rectangle destRect;
    Rectangle sourceRect;
    Rectangle destRectSmall;
    Rectangle sourceRectSmall;

    PlayerSprite player;
    KeyboardState keyboardState;

    float elapsed;
    float delay = 90f;
    int frameCount = 0;

    public const int screenHeight = 550;
    public const int screenWidth = 800;

    public MainGame()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);

        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = screenHeight;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = screenWidth;

        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
    /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
    /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
    /// and initialize them as well.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        destRect = new Rectangle(100, 100, 60, 60);
        destRectSmall = new Rectangle(100, 300, 20, 20);
        base.Initialize();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
    /// all of your content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        coinCount = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("CoinCount");

        platformsList = new List<PlatformSprite>();
        pickUpList = new List<Consumable>();
        //healthBarsList = new List<Texture2D>();
        staticEnemyList = new List<StaticEnemy>();

        coinAnim = Content.Load<Texture2D>("CoinSpinAnim");
        coinAnimBig = Content.Load<Texture2D>("CoinAnim");
        floatingPlatform = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Platform1");
        groundPlatform = Content.Load<Texture2D>("GroundPlatform1");
        redPlayer = Content.Load<Texture2D>("TestSprite");
        spikeEnemy = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Spike");

        //healthEmpty = Content.Load<Texture2D>("HealthBarEmpty");
        //health1 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("HealthBar1");
        //health2 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("HealthBar2");
        //health3 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("HealthBar3");
        //health4 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("HealthBar4");
        //health5 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("HealthBar5");
        //health6 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("HealthBar6");
        //health7 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("HealthBar7");
        //health8 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("HealthBar8");
        //health9 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("HealthBar9");
        //healthFull = Content.Load<Texture2D>("HealthBarFull");
        //healthBarsList.Add(healthEmpty);
        //healthBarsList.Add(health1);
        //healthBarsList.Add(health2);
        //healthBarsList.Add(health3);
        //healthBarsList.Add(health4);
        //healthBarsList.Add(health5);
        //healthBarsList.Add(health6);
        //healthBarsList.Add(health7);
        //healthBarsList.Add(health8);
        //healthBarsList.Add(health9);
        //healthBarsList.Add(healthFull);

        platformsList.Add(new PlatformSprite(groundPlatform, new Vector2(0, 454)));
        platformsList.Add(new PlatformSprite(floatingPlatform, new Vector2(500, 330)));
        platformsList.Add(new PlatformSprite(floatingPlatform, new Vector2(100, 290)));
        platformsList.Add(new PlatformSprite(floatingPlatform, new Vector2(300, 250)));
        platformsList.Add(new PlatformSprite(floatingPlatform, new Vector2(170, 250)));
        platformsList.Add(new PlatformSprite(floatingPlatform, new Vector2(350, 360)));

        staticEnemyList.Add(new StaticEnemy(spikeEnemy, platformsList[0], 300));

        pickUpList.Add(new Consumable(coinAnim, platformsList[1], 30, sourceRectSmall));
        pickUpList.Add(new Consumable(coinAnim, platformsList[3], 45, sourceRectSmall));
        pickUpList.Add(new Consumable(coinAnim, platformsList[4], 60, sourceRectSmall));

        player = new PlayerSprite(redPlayer, platformsList, pickUpList, staticEnemyList, 0);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
    /// all content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
        // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
    /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // Allows the game to exit
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();

        keyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();

        //currentHealthTexture = healthBarsList[player.playerHealth];

        player.Update(keyboardState);

        elapsed += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;

        if (elapsed >= delay)
        {
            if (frameCount >= 5)
            {
                frameCount = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                frameCount++;
            }

            elapsed = 0;
        }

        sourceRect = new Rectangle(60 * frameCount, 0, 60, 60);
        sourceRectSmall = new Rectangle(20 * frameCount, 0, 20, 20);

        foreach (Consumable c in pickUpList)
        {
            c.Update();
        }

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        spriteBatch.Begin();

        foreach (PlatformSprite p in platformsList)
        {
            p.Draw(spriteBatch);
        }

        foreach (Consumable c in pickUpList)
        {
            c.Draw(spriteBatch, sourceRectSmall);
        }

        foreach (StaticEnemy se in staticEnemyList)
        {
            se.Draw(spriteBatch);
        }

        //spriteBatch.Draw(currentHealthTexture, new Vector2(680, 10), Color.White);

        spriteBatch.DrawString(coinCount, ":  " + player.playerCoinCount, new Vector2(30, 10), Color.White);
        spriteBatch.Draw(coinAnim, new Rectangle(10, 10, 20, 20), new Rectangle(0, 0, 20, 20), Color.White);


        player.Draw(spriteBatch);

        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

As you can see I've commented out all of the health bar code, I hope this adds detail to my question but really sorry if this is a terrible question I just have no clue what to do or where to start to fix it.

TEMPORARY UPDATE - FIXED IT!! :D

I narrowed it down to one single while loop that caused this 'build but not launch' error. I tried a few times commenting the loop out and then bringing it back on the table again and every time I commented it out it launched the game successfully. I'm on my phone right know so I apologise for not quoting the exact loop yet but it was a while loop, something like:
    int j :0;
    while (j < staticEnemyList.Count)
    {
        if(player.enclosedRectangle.Intersects              (staticEnemyList[i].GetRectangle))
    {
        playerHealth--
    }
    else
    {
        j++
    }
}

I think it has something to do with setting the enemy list index as 'i' instead of j but this didn't return an error as I had a loop before this base on an integer called 'i'. Still have no clue as to why this while loop broke visual studio, any suggestions would be cool? Again I am so sorry for my terrible format etc as soon as I get on my computer I will update with the actual while loop code. Thanks everyone who commented, great advice - AGAIN... sorry - really difficult to comment on phone and I can't answer within 8 hours, this is only temporary :)

Comment: Uh oh how do yoy format

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: Might as well try it, nothing else is working.

Comment: There's way too much going on in your main game loop. Also, I'd look into MonoGame, which is still supported - unlike XNA.

Comment: As an aside, since you're still learning, can I suggest putting all of the healthbar images in a single texture file and just drawing the correct one using different sourcerects?

Comment: You mean where I've set the screen dimensions or another loop? but yes I shall do that thanks, and oh okay, yeah that makes a lot more sense, although this won't fix the 'Not launching' bug. But thanks for the tips :D

Comment: @CompleteNoob: Everything in Update and Draw is part of the main game loop. Almost all of what is currently in there should be delegated to different classes as soon as possible. You really don't want to deal with the resulting mess otherwise. A simple improvement may be to place all your objects with Draw methods into either Components (requiring `.OfType<IDrawable>`) or perhaps a `List<IDrawable>` so you only need one loop for them all. The main game loop has very few roles it should be filling. Don't let it do too much.

Comment: but surely in the end the system is carrying out all the same amount of code as before if not more? sorry I know you're right it's just I don't know the architecture at all I'm just coding until things work at the moment, trying to learn what does what before I start organising my code, I appreciate the tips a lot, need all the advice I can get

Comment: @itsme86 Oh yeah so I put all the health bars into on sprite sheet, works perfectly, feels much neater, and I feel a lot smarter :D thanks a lot

Comment: You should write an answer to your own question now, rather than edit the question. But yeah, moving things out of that class may indeed result in more code. That's fine, because it keeps your concerns separated. No class should know more than it absolutely has to. That way, when one thing changes, nothing else has to.

Answer (score 0):

The project built but didn't appear because of a silly infinite while loop I created by mistake. This was made by creating a couple of different integers and not using the correct integer with its corresponding while loop. A simple problem really easy to fix but for someone who is new to C# this can seem really intimidating.